# MySQL query in a database of food inventory and recipes

Tags: mysql, subquery, multiple-tables

I'm new to mysql and I have to do a kitchen inventory database with recipes for a school project. I'm trying to get a query that shows recipes and users when users have all the ingredients to that recipe. I'm trying to work with the following tables for this query:

**Products**

- ProdID
- name (brand included)
- tag - FK

**Tags** (Since there are different brands of products, a tag table to associate each product to a generic type, like orange juice)

- TagID
- name

**Recipes**

- RecipeID
- Name
- Description

**Ingredients** (To associate all the ingredients with each recipe)

- IgrID
- TagID - FK
- RecipeID - FK

**Inventory**

- InvID
- UserID
- ProductID - FK
- QTY

My idea was to get all the ingredients a user have and then check if they complete a recipe, but I don't know how to put together all the tables to get the first part. I tought of doing a join with users ingredients and recipes for the second part, I don't know if it would work though. Maybe the structure I made is unnecessarily complex too. Could anyone give me a hand?

Comment: Do you want to show all recipes and (essentially) a Y/N that shows if a person can make recipe? Or do you want to show only exact matches, meaning that if a person is missing just 1 ingredient from every recipe, the query result will be empty?

Comment: One way to do this is to have multiple tables for `FROM` like so: `SELECT * FROM Products AS P, Inventory AS I, Ingredients AS IG WHERE P.ProdID = I.ProductID AND P.tag = IG.TagID`.

Comment: @matigo I'm trying to get a query that shows all recipes an user can do with their ingredients.